# Any combination of nilpotent operators is still nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> If $N$ and $N'$ are nilpotent operator on a vector space and $N$ commutes with $N'$ then $N+N'$ is nilpotent.

$$(N+N')^r=\sum_{j=0}^r \binom{r}{j}N^j(N')^{r-j}=0$$ for some r large enough. but it seems if $N$ does not commute with $N'$, $N+N'$ is still nilpotent. So, Can I say that any combination of nilpotent operators is still nilpotent?

Comment: No, a sum of two nilpotent (non-commuting) operators need not be nilpotent.  Try the $2\times 2$ example that takes $N' = N^T$,

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't: take $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $A+B$ squares to the identity and isn't nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

For operators on a finite dimensional vector spaces you can actually characterize the sum of nilpotent operators (i.e. square matrices).

**Lemma** Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Then $A$ is the sum of (at most three) nilpotent operators if and only if $\mbox{tr}(A)$.

**Proof** Since any nilpotent operator has trace $0$ the $\Rightarrow$ implication is obvious.

$\Leftarrow$.

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a matrix with $\mbox{tr}(A)=0$.

Then
$$A= B+C$$ where
$$B= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}& a_{11} & ...&a_{11}\\
a_{22}& a_{22} & ...&a_{22}\\
a_{33}& a_{33} & ...&a_{33}\\
...&...&...&...\\
a_{nn}& a_{nn} & ...&a_{nn}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $C_{ii}=0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Next, $\mbox{tr}(A)=0$ implies that $B^2=0$.

Moreover, $C$ can be written in an obvious way as the sum of two nilpotent matrices:

$$C= \begin{bmatrix}
0& c_{12} & ...&c_{1n}\\
0& 0 & ...&c_{2n}\\
0& 0 & ...&c_{3n}\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&0 & ...&0\\
\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}
0& 0 & ...&0\\
c_{21}& 0 & ...&0\\
c_{31}&c_{32} & ...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
c_{n1}& c_{n2} & ...&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
i.e. the sum of a strictly upper triangular and a strictly lower triangular matrix.

\qed

Now your question becomes equivalent to : is any matrix with $\mbox{tr}(A)=0$ nilpotent? It is trivial to find invertible matrices with trace 0.